# Current Android device admin API and accessibility API Play Store restrictions

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-permissions

in late 2017, Google started restricting device admin API and accessibility API for all future and current Play Store apps that don't use them for their intended purpose, but they stopped restricting it for 30 days to reevaluate it and then all the news stopped.

I couldn't find anything in the Google's developer content policies. Does anyone know what are the current restrictions regarding device admin API and accessibility API? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't strictly about code, but about a third-party policy that is in the process of changing and will probably continue to change. So, it seems a bit off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about vendor policies.